# Java script keypress event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the keypress event in my project to start a countdown timer but I keep getting a decrement for every keystroke.
I don't know what's wrong with my js code.

```
var timeleft = 60;
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');

var input = document.getElementById("input");
var timerId = setInterval(countdown);
input.addEventListener("keypress", countdown, 1000);

function countdown(event) {
    if (event.key !==undefined){
       
        if (timeleft == -1) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
        else {
            timer.innerHTML = timeleft;
            timeleft--;
        }
    }
    
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure what you are expecting? Your code will execute on each keyPress, at least `60` / `61` times. This is what you've coded.

Comment: thank you, I was trying to write program starts my timer when I begin typing and character on my keyboard